# Is there a way to set the function pointer according to user parameter?

Tags: c++, vtable

I have one version of code with benchmark surround with macros to enable or disable, and I want to change the code that I can turn on and off the benchmark settings without recompiling my code and without a lot of if-else or without code duplication (version with the benchmark and a version without)?

A way to set the vtable for the correct functions?

**EDIT:** added code sample for what I don't wont to do

**EDIT V2** I understood from the answers that there isn't a way, so if I create two shared object can I code on run time to which one to link to?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct A
{

   virtual int add(int a,int b)=0;
};

struct B:public A
{
     virtual int add(int a,int b){return a+b;}

};

struct C:public A
{
     virtual int add(int a,int b)
     {
         cout << "time" << endl;
         return a+b;
         }

};


int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    A* a;
    string s(argv[1]);
    if(s.compare("t"))
    {
        a = new C;
    }
    else
    {
        a=new B;
    }
    cout << a->add(2,5);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Using standard C++? No, as vtables is an implementation detail that is outside the scope of C++.

Comment: It would help if you could create a small code sample to demonstrate your problem. There are many ways to inject code in C++, especially if you are free to make changes to the original code. For instance you can create a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Comment: @decorator i added code sample

Comment: Why do you feel the need to reason on term of vtables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. With the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), you avoid code duplication.
For the abstract class `A` a decorator printing the time would look like this:

```
struct TimedA : public A
{
     TimedA(A* base) : base_(base) {}
     virtual int add(int a,int b)
     {
         cout << "time" << endl;
         return base_->add(a, b);
     }

     A* base_;
};
```

The point of the decorator is that you can append it to any object of type `A` and it will inject the additional behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> A way to set the vtable for the correct functions?

Vtable is an implementation detail. The way this detail is normally implemented is that the vtable pointer is set by the constructor.

You can have one interface and a factory function pointer that you set once and use many times (also known as [Factory design pattern](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Factory)). E.g.:

```
#include <memory>

struct A {
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual ~A() noexcept = default;
};

std::unique_ptr<A>(*factory)(); // Factory function.

struct A1 : A {
    void f() override;
};

struct A2 : A {
    void f() override;
};

int main(int ac, char** av) {
    if(ac >= 1 && **av == 'd')
        factory = []() { return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A2); };
    else
        factory = []() { return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A1); };

    auto a = factory();
}
```

Comment: the factory design pattern I know, I tried to find a why not to use it because the meaning fo using it is to have code duplication of the functions, but tnx